# how to add the Hero Cards in bot conversation using Form Flow concept.

Tags: botframework

I am working bot framework technology, in one of my project I want to display the Hero Card in Forms.

For that scenario I used Form Flow concept for developing my own form, but I got struggled to add Hero Card in the middle of my Form Conversation with my bot.

I followed the below document for Hero Card Coding using C#.
http://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html

And also followed the below document for developing my own Form Using Form Flow concept.
http://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/forms.html

Please tell me how to add the Hero Cards in bot conversation using Form Flow concept.

-Pradeep